# Cannot receive properly serialized struct with nlohmann::json via named pipes

Tags: c++, unix, serialization, pipe, ipc

I have 2 processes (applications both written in C++) and I want to achieve the following functionality:

1. First process (server application) will receive some data from a source (in my case, informations regarding some signals from CAN BUS). This application will compute these details in a struct with different members and the struct will be serialized (I use nhlomann::json). After the serialization is done, the application will send via a UNIX pipe the stream bytes (std::vector<uint8_t> to the client process.
2. Client process will read from the pipe the serialized data and it should deserialize and read the details from the struct

Here is some code:

1. Server app side

   ```
    //create the signal informations which the client will receive
    //test only with value data at this moment
    sigHandlerLib::signalInfo sigToClient;
    sigToClient.signalValue = value;

    //serialize the content 
    nlohmann::json json = sigToClient;
    std::vector<uint8_t> serializedBuffer = nlohmann::json::to_bson(json);
    std::size_t serializedBufferSize = sizeof(serializedBuffer);

    std::cout << "Serialized buffer size: " << serializedBufferSize << '\n';
    std::cout << "Buffer content size: " << serializedBuffer.size() << '\n';

    ...

    //notify clients
    const auto iter = std::find_if(clientSignalNotifications.begin(), clientSignalNotifications.end(), [&updatedSignal](const auto& iter) { return (iter.first.first.compare(updatedSignal) == 0); });
    if(iter != clientSignalNotifications.end())
    {
        for(const auto& client : iter->second)
        {
            writeToIpcNamedPipe(client, serializedBuffer, serializedBufferSize);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "[Signal Handler Service]: No client subscribed for this signal, no notification is sent" << '\n';
    }
   ```

Function which will write the serialized data to pipe:

```
    const std::string ipcLocationPath = "/tmp/" + processName + ".ipc";

    int ipcFileDescriptor = open(ipcLocationPath.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(ipcFileDescriptor != -1 && ipcFileDescriptor != EEXIST)
    {
        int nbytes = 0;
        nbytes = write(ipcFileDescriptor, &buffer, bufferSize);
        if(nbytes == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "[Signal Handler Service] Cannot write to IPC file data, error code = " << errno << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[Signal Handler Service] Data sent to client " << processName << '\n';
            std::cout << "[Signal Handler Service] Bytes written to IPC Pipe: " << nbytes << '\n';
            std::cout << "[Signal Handler Service] Number of the elements in the buffer " << buffer.size() << '\n';

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(150));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "[Signal Handler Service] Cannot open IPC pipe for writing, error code = " << errno << '\n';
    }

    close(ipcFileDescriptor);
```

2. Client app side (logic where data is read from pipe and deserialized)

   ```
     std::vector<uint8_t> deserializedBytes;

     pollfd readPoll;

     timeval selectTimeout;
     selectTimeout.tv_sec = 2;
     selectTimeout.tv_usec = 0;

     while(1)
     {
         memset(&readPoll, 0, sizeof(readPoll));
         readPoll.fd = ipcDescriptor;
         readPoll.events = POLLIN;

         //std::cout << "[Signal Handler Library] Starting reading from IPC logic" << '\n';

         std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
         //std::cout << "[Signal Handler Library] Thread ID = " << this_id << '\n';

         int pollReturn = 0;
         pollReturn = poll(&readPoll, 1, 2000);
         if(pollReturn > 0)
         {
             size_t nbytes = 0;
             nbytes = read(ipcDescriptor, deserializedBytes.data(), deserializedBytes.size());
             if(nbytes <= 0)
             {
                  //std::cout << "[Signal Handler Library] Cannot read data from IPC, error code = " << errno << '\n';
             }
             else                        
             {  
                 std::cout << "Buffer received with size: " << nbytes << '\n';
                 std::cout << "Buffer content size: " << deserializedBytes.size() << '\n';


                 //deserialize the content
                 auto deserializedJson = nlohmann::json::from_bson(deserializedBytes);

                 if(deserializedJson.size() != 0)
                 {
                     sigHandlerLib::signalInfo recvSignal = deserializedJson.get<sigHandlerLib::signalInfo>();

                     std::cout << "[Signal Handler Library] Signal value: " << recvSignal.signalValue << '\n';    
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     std::cout << "[Signal Handler Library] There was an error at data deserialization!" << '\n';
                 }       
             }        
         }
         else
         {
             //std::cout << "[Signal Handler Library] Poll error from IPC, error code = " << errno << ". poll result = " << pollReturn << '\n';
         }
     }
   ```

The issue is: the client application crashes. What I am doing wrong. From logs, it seems that the content of the bytes stream readen from the pipe is not ok (the deserializedBytes.size() = a very huge number after "read" function call).

Comment: Just a guess ... AFAICT, you define `deserializedBytes` as a default. But, when you do: `read(ipcDescriptor, deserializedBytes.data(), deserializedBytes.size());` the vector is empty [and `.data()` may return null?]. Shouldn't you increase the size before calling this with (e.g.) `deserializedBytes.reserve()`?

Comment: Thanks for hint, I will give a try tommorow. However, what should be the size which should be reserved for deserializedBytes? Should be at least sizeof of the serialiezed counterpart ?

Comment: Please don't add tags into the question title. There is a special field for them.